# .Net core, error when scaffolding with entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to create a controller leveraging the scaffolding with Entity Framework option, but it simply is not working, giving the error bellow:
[image]

The .csproj is here:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="6.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc" Version="1.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.1" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="1.0.1" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

And my DbContext has the DbSet to the Model I'm trying to use in the scaffolding:

```
public DbSet<Tarefa> Tarefas { get; set; }
```

I've tried not only with the Model, but also with the ViewModel, but the result is the same.
Could anyone give a tip of what I'm missing?

Comment: Can you please share `DbContext` and `Tarefa` model class?

Comment: Hey @Sanket, here you are:
DbContext: https://github.com/Tmaturano/Tarefas/blob/master/Tarefas.Infrastructure.Data/Context/TarefasEFContext.cs

Tarefa class:https://github.com/Tmaturano/Tarefas/blob/master/Tarefas.Domain/Entities/Tarefa.cs